# Multiple entries with same key, Project Structure doesn't run

Tags: java, android, ide, structure, project

Error Message while running the project structure:

```
Multiple entries with same key: Google Inc.:Google APIs:23=Google APIs (API 23) and Google Inc.:Google APIs:23=Google APIs (API 23)
```

Details of the error:

```
Multiple entries with same key: Google Inc.:Google APIs:23=Google APIs (API 23) and Google Inc.:Google APIs:23=Google APIs (API 23)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: Google Inc.:Google APIs:23=Google APIs (API 23) and Google Inc.:Google APIs:23=Google APIs (API 23)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:150)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableBiMap.<init>(RegularImmutableBiMap.java:77)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap$Builder.build(ImmutableBiMap.java:172)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.KeyValuePane.<init>(KeyValuePane.java:138)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.AndroidProjectConfigurable.<init>(AndroidProjectConfigurable.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.<init>(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:41)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.getInstance(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.showAndroidProjectStructure(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ChameleonAction.actionPerformed(ChameleonAction.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:281)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Is there a question? Do you have code that you have trouble with? Maybe some data you read, or provided, have this key twice: `Google Inc.:Google APIs:23`

Comment: Exactly, why this happened? Went to file>project structure, and nothing happened, only this error message in the log. Even if it is a new project.

Comment: Don't you think saying that in the question would be a good thing? Saying where/when the error occurs? Sounds like your installation is bad. Try re-installing.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if i hadn't tried the basic things already.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and managed to solve uninstalling the (Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) google APIs on "SDK Manager", restarted the AndroidStudio and reinstalled using the SDK "Sync" ...
It works! Remember to give the unistall and reinstall the API 23 only this is enough if you already have the "Android SDK Platform 23" installed. The solution is to reinstall the Google APIs.

Comment: where is the SDK "Sync" ...
??

Answer (score 0):

You must use Android Studio build-in SDK Manager to avoid this problem.
Try to install your missing "Google API" from there.